# Silly Problem Referencing a Post ID

Tags: amazon

Hey there I have a stupid problem I'm having trying to integrate a button in wordpress. I have a plugin called wp azon builder which has an onsite cart button (add to cart stays on site) then I have the theme knightzon which has a cart button but the knightzon button links to amazon directly. I need to change this so it adds to onsitecart like the plugin.

I have it mostly figured out I just can't seem to reference the post id from outside the plugin framework. Sounds easy I'm just tired of it.

http://www.syracusefanpages.com

You can see what I'm trying to do in the slider I have it almost working LOL, and I included a working button example in the list view, but its pointing to a static product for demonstration purposes. I'd like to use the gray button image.

**Update**

I need to know how to call the page ID, I guess? This is what I was using:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
```

Here is the plugin button code from the source, (what I want):

```
// on-site cart 
if (get_option('amzn-onsitecart') == "Yes") { 
    $addtocartcode = '<a [relnofollow] [targetblank] title="[Title]" href="#" onClick="amzn_onsitecartAdd('."'". $postid ."'".');" class="amzn_buynowimage amzn_addtocart_onsite_link"><img src="[PluginURL]/buttons/'.$addtocartimg.'"></a>'; 
}
```

Here is what I have currently (it doesn't see the button function I'm guessing from not properly calling the post id)

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href= '#' onclick="amzn_onsitecartAdd('<?php the_post(); ?>');" class="amzn_buynowimage amzn_addtocart_onsite_link"><img(can't-post-image here so remove this)) src="http://www.syracusefanpages.com/wp-content/plugins/amzn/buttons/_addtocart-legacy.png"></a>;
```

The gray button from theme is what I'd like to use but that's not important, I just can't get the function to function, :-)

Comment: Please edit your question to include any and all relevant code. Otherwise, we have no possible way to try to answer the question.

Comment: Your usage of `the_post` suggests that you are missing critically important knowledge of basic post loops. I **STRONGLY** suggest you read this: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012 else you may be incapable of using or understanding any answers given to you

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised, your site works as desired, if you really call [`the_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) for the button. This function does not echo the post's ID, it simply fetches the next post of the current query.

If I understood you correctly (and I'm not so sure about that), you only want to get the current post's ID so you can work with it, right?

All you need to do is call [`the_ID();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) wherever you want to output the ID. If you want to pass it to a function or in some way want to work with the data, use [`get_the_ID();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) instead.

In your case, this would be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="amzn_onsitecartAdd('<?php the_ID(); ?>');" ...
```